# Add current movies to Netflix queue

Tags: netflix

I used to have the DVD service and I added current movies in my queue so I would get them when they were released. I just renewed my membership but changed to streaming. Is there a way to add current movies to the Instant Queue?

Answer (score 1):

No, because currently you can only add items to your Instant Queue if they're available for streaming. While anything in theaters now is virtually guaranteed to come out on DVD in a few months, the same can't be said for streaming.

Unless and until Hollywood gets its act together and allows everything to be streamed, I expect the status quo to remain.