# Track unreleased movies in Netflix

Tags: netflix

When I search Netflix for movies that they don't have yet, it shows no result.

How can I add unreleased movies to my Netflix list so that I know when they are available on Netflix?

I was a customer in the US about 5 years ago and I'm pretty sure this was possible back then. I used to add movies to my watch list even before they were in theatre.

I re-opened my account now and the UI is completely different...

Comment: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/39692/create-a-list-of-movies-id-like-to-watch-on-netflix/

Comment: @EightDaysofMalaise that link does not provide any solution

Comment: Related: [Add current movies to Netflix queue](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/26797/354)

Comment: Indeed I see it's not possible built-in. But no one found a work around using a third party tool?